# Select from table depending on a parameter in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I'm a writing a 'simple' SQL function that selects data, depending on a parameter in the `WHERE` clause :

```
DECLARE @csp AS CHAR(1) = 'F'

SELECT  [NUMERO_DOSSIER]
FROM    [dbo].[Dossier]
WHERE   
    [CSP] IN
    (
        CASE @csp
            WHEN 'F' THEN
                (SELECT [CSP] FROM [dbo].[CSP_1])
            WHEN 'N' THEN
                (SELECT [CSP] FROM [dbo].[CSP_2])
            END
    )
```

This query has no syntax error according to SQL Server 2012. But running it returns this error :

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

To my understanding, the problem here is : the `CASE` function returns scalars, and can't return a table.

How can I rewrite this to make it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `CASE` in a `WHERE` clause -- it usually makes the logic more complicated.  Just expand the logic as boolean logic:

```
WHERE ( @csp = 'F' AND [CSP] IN (SELECT [CSP] FROM [dbo].[CSP_1]) ) OR
      ( @csp = 'N' AND [CSP] IN (SELECT [CSP] FROM [dbo].[CSP_2]) )
```

Comment: Using `@csp = 'F'` inside the condition is actually pretty clever. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One method is with a `UNION ALL` subquery:

```
SELECT  [NUMERO_DOSSIER]
FROM    [dbo].[Dossier]
WHERE   
    [CSP] IN
    (
        SELECT [CSP] 
        FROM [dbo].[CSP_1]
        WHERE @csp = 'F'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [CSP] 
        FROM [dbo].[CSP_2]
        WHERE @csp = 'N'
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two `CTE`s and two `JOIN` operations:

```
DECLARE @csp AS CHAR(1) = 'F'

;WITH Table1 AS (
    SELECT [CSP] 
    FROM [dbo].[CSP_1]
), Table2 AS (
    SELECT [CSP] 
    FROM [dbo].[CSP_2]
)
SELECT  [NUMERO_DOSSIER]
FROM  [dbo].[Dossier] AS d
JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON @csp = 'F' AND d.CSP = t1.CSP
JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON @csp = 'N' AND d.CSP = t2.CSP
```

**Edit:**

After seeing @Dan's answer, this is probably cleaner:

```
;WITH Table1 AS (
    SELECT [CSP] 
    FROM [dbo].[CSP_1]
    WHERE @csp = 'F'
), Table2 AS (
    SELECT [CSP] 
    FROM [dbo].[CSP_2]
    WHERE @csp = 'N'
)
SELECT  [NUMERO_DOSSIER]
FROM  [dbo].[Dossier] AS d
JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON d.CSP = t1.CSP
JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON d.CSP = t2.CSP
```